# Is WSDL is used to describe WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

WSDL stands for web service description language and is used to describe Web Service, so is it used to describe WCF also, and if yes than whether svcutil.exe is only tool used in WCF to describe data by WSDL. Also for WCF it is said that it works on Service oriented architecutre so ASP.net WebService also work on same or different architecutre.

Comment: I am comparing ASP.net WebService with WCF which are different

Comment: Yeah, ASMX services have been replaced by WCF. ASMX is a legacy technology that should not be used for new development.

Comment: But why serivce oriented architecture is only attached with WCF and not ASMX Service. What makes WCF as service oriented architecutre and ASMX service not

Comment: It has nothing to do with SOA. ASMX was the SOAP offering from Microsoft in .NET 1.0. WCF replaced it. WCF is _far_ more flexible and implements the modern SOA standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL is used to help a consumer to understand how to to *consume* a web service. WCF is a technology that can be used to create and consume web services. WCF is one of may enabling technologies that can be used to implement an SOA. WCF is a newer, more flexible and configurable web service technology than ASMX.